# zsh for loop over command output

Tags: zsh

I store the output of a command as such.

```
all=(`some command`)

for i in $all; do
  echo $i
done
```

this returns output like this.

```
string1a string1b string1c
string2a string2b string2c
string3a string3b string3c
```

however i want to be able to access just a part of the value of i, where space is the separator. for example output like this.

```
string1a string1c
string2a string2c
string3a string3c
```

how do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
% print -l 'string1a string1b string1c' 'string2a string2b string2c' \
        'string3a string3b string3c'
string1a string1b string1c
string2a string2b string2c
string3a string3b string3c
% all=( "$( print -l 'string1a string1b string1c' 'string2a string2b string2c' 
    'string3a string3b string3c' )" )
% print -l ${all//string<->b }
string1a string1c
string2a string2c
string3a string3c
%
```

- `$(...)` does the same as backticks, but is preferred because it can be nested, whereas backticks can not.
- `"$(...)"` ensures line breaks are preserved.
- `${foo//bar}` removes from parameter `$foo` all substrings that match the pattern `bar`.
- `<->` matches any number.
- `print -l` prints each argument on a separate line.

Alternatively, you can also do this without creating the parameter `$all`:

```sh
% print -l ${"$(
    print -l 'string1a string1b string1c' 'string2a string2b string2c' \
      'string3a string3b string3c'
  )"//string<->b }
string1a string1c
string2a string2c
string3a string3c
%
```